# "Catch a distant trumpet"

Tags: idioms

What is the proper interpretation of "catch a distant trumpet of an entirely new point of view"? (I only know that an American artist wrote this and that she was in England at the time.)

> *January 19:* I fly on the night of January 23rd. I know that as my foot crosses the threshold of the airplane, my spirit will lift. In my guidebook I have scouted out the topography of Paris so that when I arrive I can align myself north, south, east, west. And I continue to review my French.
>
> French money is engraved with the portraits of artists: Delacroix, de La Tour, Montesquieu, Debussy; I am astounded, and catch a distant trumpet of an entirely new point of view. I wonder if, by way of similar extraordinary facts that I cannot predict, I may feel more at home in Europe than on my deeply loved stretches of land in the United States. Something stubborn in me hopes not, and in recognizing that part of me I suddenly know why I never sought out Europe when, for years of my life, I had ample opportunity: I am afraid of its wisdoms, leery of challenge to the little developments of my own that I have struggled for and the independence of which I cherish, perhaps inordinately.

Comment: She probably means she hears the sound of a distant trumpet. Absent more information, this would seem to be an idiosyncratic utterance.

Comment: I'd say it's simply a metaphor: a distant trumpet [heralds](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/herald) the arrival of [the King, etc]. According to the Sat I Reasoning Test, it was used by a U.S. painter and sculptor on her first visit to Paris.

Comment: The quotation seems to be from Anne Truitt, [_Turn: The Journal of an Artist_](https://books.google.com/books?id=UDkbAAAAIAAJ&q=%22catch+a+distant+trumpet+of+an+entirely+new+point%22&dq=%22catch+a+distant+trumpet+of+an+entirely+new+point%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRnpifx6PgAhVuHDQIHf9BCUoQ6AEIKjAA) (1986). You can find her [Wikipedia page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Truitt).

Comment: Literally, "catch a distant trumpet" would mean to hear the faint sound of the trumpet in the distance.  But the author is speaking figuratively, of a sort of French/European spirit that is "heard" in the distance.

Comment: Like @Chappo I believe that the metaphor refers to an heraldic trumpet rather than a modern orchestral trumpet. It reads to me that Truitt is saying that the sight of pictures of artists on pre-Euro French money began a deep and slow change in her view of the world. The "distant trumpet" indicates that, at first, only the possibility of change occurred to her; details of the nature of the change would become clear only later in the way that the nature of an advancing force would only become clear as they came closer.

Comment: @Sven Yargs  Good call!  I see it on page 112. That is all I can view on that page from the link you provided. I'll borrow the book from a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret "a distant trumpet" to mean that the author realizes that the French seem to value artistic contributions above political contributions, since their money portrays artists and not politicians, as does US currency.

The metaphor of a distant trumpet (in my opinion) is meant to convey that it is not clear exactly what the French think of artists, similar to that you might have trouble making out what song a distant trumpeter is playing.

I think it also conveys a sense of attraction, that the author is drawn to, and would like to learn more about a philosophy that values artistic contributions, as you might walk toward a distant trumpet to hear the song more clearly.

As *A gal named Desire* mentioned below, it could also indicate an announcement of something, maybe a new chapter in the author's life, or her integration into a community with values that are so much different than those she experienced in the US.

Comment: I associate a trumpet with important announcements. My interpretation was that the French culture was calling to her to stay and to learn.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with some of the comments and answers posted before. However, in general literature, the call of a trumpet in the distance is to herald the arrival of something. In this figuration, I would then think that what is being heralded, as the author describes, is the *new point of view*.

The idea that the trumpet is distant is the metaphor that could otherwise be explained with a different metaphor, such as a *seed beginning to sprout*.  The author can sense the change in an internal point of view. It isn't finalized, but at that point it's a bit of a discovery moment: In France, the arts are of the highest regard over politics, to the extent of the nation's greatest contributors to the art are present in money. As the author is an artist as well, this a point of resonance.

Therefore, the *distant trumpet* is the metaphoric inaudible **call to action** for the arrival of this point of view, that the author experiences and resonates with, giving the author the sense of belonging that is unexpected but also more aligned with personal beliefs.

Comment: Your explanation is compelling.

Comment: It is in the same vein as the (edited) explanation offered by `mRotten`.

Answer (score 0):

Trumpets are used to announce that something is beginning. A distant trumpet is one whose sound is faint when it reaches you. If she moves in the direction of the trumpet she will experience what it has announced: she will soon experience something novel to her, a culture that celebrates its artists to the extent that their likenesses are put on money. This new experience is on the horizon for her.

Answer (score 0):

> ... and catch a distant trumpet (in her mind as an announcement) of an entirely new point of view ...

The figurative use of a trumpet is not heard but sensed in the mind:

[The World Book Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=oPW_pTjpeCQC&lpg=PA2243&dq=sounded%20a%20figurative%20trumpet&pg=PA2243#v=onepage&q=sounded%20a%20figurative%20trumpet&f=false)

> to announce **as if** by sound of trumpet